# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.[data-target='2.nj.ryan']?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<p>Filter: </p>
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">Show All</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<p>Location: </p>
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">All Locations</option>
  <option value="nj">NJ</option>
  <option value="ny">NY</option>
  <option value="pa">PA</option>
</select>

<p>Test: </p>
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">All Locations</option>
  <option value="ryan">Ryan</option>
  <option value="ny">NY</option>
  <option value="pa">PA</option>
</select>


<div id="FilterContainer">
  <div data-target="all 1 nj">Test One NJ</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 ny">Test One NY</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 nj ryan">Test Two NJ Ryan</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 pa">Test Two PA</div>
  <div data-target="all 3 nj">Test Three NJ</div>
  <div data-target="all 3 ny">Test Three NY</div>
  <div data-target="all 3 pa ryan">Test Three PA Ryan</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 nj">Test One NJ</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 nj ryan">Test Two NJ Ryan</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 ny ryan">Test Two NY Ryan</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return $(e).val();
    }).join(".");
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div").hide();
    
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div.[data-target='"+ filters +"']").show();
});
</script>
```

`div.[data-target='"+ filters +"'` this line should be error. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Should be `div[data-target= ...`, no "." between "div" and "[".

Comment: @Pointy removing the `.` fixes the syntax error but doesn't filter the list as intended. However, the OP does seem to be at least a few steps away from getting it working...

Comment: error fixed but filter not working

Comment: Well instead of typing "how to solve this problem" over and over again, you could have taken the time to describe what you expect to happen.

Comment: `.join(".");` should be `.join(" ");`

Comment: The whole approach makes rather little sense. Say I chose One, NJ, all - then the filter value you'd be creating, is `1.nj.all`, or if you replace the dots by spaces, `1 nj all` - but _none_ of your elements actually has that as the full value of its `data-target` attribute.

Comment: @CBroe It's not that far off. [See my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167674/227299)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems:

- `div.[attr]` is invalid. There should be no `.` in between the tag name and the brackets
- Attribute selectors are not like class selectors, you cannot use `.` to look for multiple of them in a space separated list of words.

  - Solution: use multiple attribute selectors such as `[data-attr~="word"][data-attr~="word2"]`

```html
<p>Filter: </p>
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">Show All</option>
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>

<p>Location: </p>
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">All Locations</option>
  <option value="nj">NJ</option>
  <option value="ny">NY</option>
  <option value="pa">PA</option>
</select>

<p>Test: </p>
<select class="filterby">
  <option value="all">All Locations</option>
  <option value="ryan">Ryan</option>
  <option value="ny">NY</option>
  <option value="pa">PA</option>
</select>


<div id="FilterContainer">
  <div data-target="all 1 nj">Test One NJ</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 ny">Test One NY</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 nj ryan">Test Two NJ Ryan</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 pa">Test Two PA</div>
  <div data-target="all 3 nj">Test Three NJ</div>
  <div data-target="all 3 ny">Test Three NY</div>
  <div data-target="all 3 pa ryan">Test Three PA Ryan</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 nj">Test One NJ</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div data-target="all 1 pa">Test One PA</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 nj ryan">Test Two NJ Ryan</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 ny">Test Two NY</div>
  <div data-target="all 2 ny ryan">Test Two NY Ryan</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("select.filterby").change(function(){
    var filters = $.map($("select.filterby").toArray(), function(e){
        return `[data-target~="${$(e).val()}"]`;
    }).join("");
    $("div#FilterContainer").find("div").hide();
    
    $("div#FilterContainer").find(`div${filters}`).show();
});
</script>
```